# updating to ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04

Tags: 16.04, boot, 18.04

I have a small old Toshiba NB200 laptop that I use for field work. When Microsoft no longer would support windows95 I loaded Ubuntu 16.04 on it. It has worked fine for a number of years. Then I made a fatal error by upgrading to version 18.04. Now it will not boot. All I get is the Ubuntu dots and then nothing. I don't even get the boot menu. How can I fix this or how can I go back to version 16.04.

Comment: Step 1: [Enable the GRUB menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time). Step 2: Select an older kernel to boot from. Try booting from newer kernels as they appear, but keep that older kernel to fall back upon.

Comment: **how can I go back to version 16.04**: In my opinion, downgrading isn't an option. Rather if you are facing serious issues, I would recommend a clean install.

Comment: Thanks at least I got a screen by pressing shift.

Comment: Thanks I decided to use a use the mint version of Linux.